# Find non-zero vectors $x, y, b $belonging to $R^3 $such that $Ax=b, By=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

where $A$ and $4$ are as follows
\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

This problem throws me off in the sense that I have to find 3 vectors. I suspect I have to use the LU factorization first in order to determine the b vector.
So I have found a decomposition for both A and B. $PA=LU; PB=LU$. I'm not sure if I started correctly or I am taking the wrong approach. Any observations are much appreciated.

[PA=LU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrFzW.gif)

[PB=LU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm1OM.gif)

Comment: What are you trying to ask,it is not clear in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the matrix $B$ is invertible (non-singular). Therefore, the equation $B\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{b}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{y}=B^{-1}\mathbf{b}$. So first you can pick vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ satisfying $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, which you can do in lots of different ways, and then calculate $\mathbf{y}=B^{-1}\mathbf{b}$.